# Não consigo dar logout No Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, login

Olá tenho uma aplicação onde a pessoa se conecta pelo firebase até ai nada demais pois isso já está tudo configurado e funcionando, então eu criei esse botão  caso a pessoa queira encerrar a sessão:
`<button onclick="logout()">logout</button>`

esse botão chama a função logout que está assim:

> ```
> function logout(){
>   firebase.auth().signOut().then(function(){
>             console.log('success');
>             window.location.replace("Login");
>         },function(){})
>     }
> ```

mais ele não dá Logout o que há de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi,

- Primeirameite cuidado ao fazer isso `<button onclick="logout()">logout</button>` 
  Porque? Porque quando  javascript estiver lendo o código que vem da ESQUERDA PRA DIREITA E DE CIMA PARA BAIXO, ele vai ver o método `logout()` já sendo executado! então ele na primeira lida já vaio executar o código.
- Eu estava dando uma olhada na documentação e seu código está quase ótimo! Olha só como está na comentação:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {

}).catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
});
```

- A diferença é que você você está passando uma espécide de callback, e isso pode estar bugando seu script, acredito que se você seguir essa documentação pode dar um resultado diferente, segue o link:
  [Docs singOutFibase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps)